Windows 10 Task Scheduler GUI window unresponsive, won't resize, won't close, shows in taskbar and taskbar popup menu close doesn't work either
I opened Task Scheduler UI window on a Windows10 PC to examine the definition of a task I created a couple of years ago,  and disable that task. I disabled the task and it shows as disabled in the task listing.The task had been running properly all that time, once a day, but is no longer needed. After disabling the task, now I cannot get the Task Scheduler UI window itself to close. It's unresponsive. Can the window be closed via Task Manager? If so, what is the Task Scheduler's UI Window called?  I don't want to shut the service itself down.

It's Microsoft Management Console, and safe to kill.
